# plotting principal components 3,4 using autoplot (ggfortify) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggfortify

I have been trying to use autoplot (in the ggfortify R package) to plot data points in PCA coordinates. For data matrix D2,

```
autoplot(prcomp(D2),colour=color_codes)
```

works fine as far a generating a scatterplot of points in the space of principal components 1+2. However, PCA components 1+2 only explain about 30% of the covariance, and I would like to do the same for PCA 1+3, 2+3, and 3+4, etc. Is there a simple argument in autoplot that will let me do this, and if not, what's the simplest function I can use to do so?

Additionally, is there some way to calculate and add centroids using autoplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?autoplot.prcomp`: 
`autoplot(object, data = NULL, scale = 1, x = 1, y = 2, ...)`
where:
`x = principal component number used in x axis` and
`y = principal component number used in y axis`

Hence, if you need to plot PC2 vs PC3 and to add the centroid:

```
library(ggfortify)
set.seed(1)
D2 <- matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol=10)

prcmp <- prcomp(D2)
pc.x <- 2
pc.y <- 3
cnt.x <- mean(prcmp$x[,pc.x])
cnt.y <- mean(prcmp$x[,pc.y])
autoplot(prcmp, x=2, y=3) +
  geom_point(x=cnt.x, y=cnt.y, colour="red", size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any built-in argument for finding/plotting centroids?

Comment: @Max By "centroids", do you mean one or more points added to the above plot with specified colors ?

Comment: Yes - if there are two or more data classes (corresponding to the color coding), I would like to plot the centroids of each data class in the PC coordinates.